# can't assign to function call, syntax error in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, list, syntax-error

I'm trying to translate a Matlab script into a Python script and, as I'm not expert in Python, I got the following error and I don't know how to solve it:

> Syntax error. There is an error in your program: *** can't assign to
>   function call

My code is:

```
import numpy.matlib
m=min(p)
Sn=numpy.zeros(28)
z=0
for i in range(init_Sn, end_Sn):
    if p(i)<=m+20 and p(i)>=m-20:
        z=z+1
        Sn(z)=1

    else:
        z=z+1
        Sn(z)=0
```

The error seems to be in the line where I do:

```
Sn(z)=1
```

I'm not sure if the problem comes from the definition of "Sn". In Matlab, all that I do is:

```
Sn=zeros(1,28)
```

I think what I'm doing in Python is not equivalent?

Comment: You need square brackets to index an array in Python `Sn[z]=1`

Comment: `Sn` is not a function but a variable name assigned to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set `Sn` on location `z` to any number, you need to call it by using `Sn[z]=1`.

Comment: thanks!! that was easy :)